# nuitka fails to generate executable due to "The filename or extension is too long"

Tags: filenames, executable, nuitka

I've been trying to compile/generate a standalone executable (.exe) with nuitka but it fails every time with the message:

Nuitka:INFO:Total memory usage before running scons: 2.72 GB (2920177664 bytes):
scons: *** [main_executable.dist\main_executable.exe] The filename or extension is too long

I'm new to this programming but I think I've tried just about everything. I moved my *.py files to directory C:\main to shorten the path to no avail. I've rename the file to produce "main.exe" from "main_executable" to no avail.

My python is installed in here:
'C:\users\test\Anaconda3...'

I came across this function below to shorten the path but I have no idea how to implement it: (taken from http://code.activestate.com/recipes/286179-getshortpathname/)

Could you kindly help. Thanks.

```
def getShortPathName(filepath):
    "Converts the given path into 8.3 (DOS) form equivalent."
    import win32api, os
    if filepath[-1] == "\\":
        filepath = filepath[:-1]
    tokens = os.path.normpath(filepath).split("\\")
    if len(tokens) == 1:
        return filepath
    ShortPath = tokens[0]
    for token in tokens[1:]:
        PartPath = "\\".join([ShortPath, token])
        Found = win32api.FindFiles(PartPath)
        if Found == []:
            raise WindowsError, 'The system cannot find the path specified: "%s"' % (PartPath)
        else:
            if Found[0][9] == "":
                ShortToken = token
            else:
                ShortToken = Found[0][9]
            ShortPath = ShortPath + "\\" + ShortToken
    return ShortPath
```